# Convert number to Date in Qlikview macro

Tags: macros, qlikview

I read a number for example 42000 that I need to convert into date in the format DD/MM/YY in a macro, not a Load statement.

In the macro the number is stored in vInput and the new value will be stored in vDate. Neither
vDatet = Date(vInput, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
or 
vDate = date(vInput#(Date,'DD/MM/YYYY')) 
works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the script below to get the content of `vInput` variable, evaluate the Qlik expression and save the result in the `vDate` variable.

Using the script below if `vInput` is equal to 42000 the `vDate` will be equal to 27/12/2014

```
sub ChangeDate

  set vInputVar = ActiveDocument.Variables("vInput")
  vInput = vInputVar.GetContent.String

  changedDate = ActiveDocument.Evaluate("=Date(" & vInput & ",'DD/MM/YYYY')")

  set vDateVar = ActiveDocument.Variables("vDate")
  vDateVar.SetContent changedDate , true

end sub
```